# Parallax caroseul using slick caroseul

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created this prototype using the `slick caroseul`. I've tried to create a `bespoke parallax` when the user swipes left/right.

Although need to enhance it further so the unseen images reset.

http://jsfiddle.net/ayve1nmf/4/

```
$(this).find(".parallaxback img:visible").animate({
   left: increment+"=15"
}, 700, function() {
   // Animation complete.
});
```

Tried to use the : visible selector, but I don't feel its having an effect.

Comment: How would you stablize this caroseul. So the elements don't float off. Also - is there a way to move the items during a slide? How do you reset the items not in vew so they can keep on track? Why does the caroseul have a snapping feel to it?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ayve1nmf/16/ - tried to improve the styling a little. I don't know why its jumping though

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ayve1nmf/25/ - I've stopped it jumping - needed to put a how many slides to jump option in. What about ensuring the background image doesn't fall out of bounds. This caroseul may need to work on full width desktop - spread just the header